# Executing javascript inside PHP scripts Issue

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to build an advert switcher, so that i can have different ads loads on mobile and desktop. Currently, if i was to insert the php includes straight into the code, it would work fine, however i wouldn't be able to make the switch based on viewport size.

My issue is that when i place them in the if statement, the script inside the php class ends the external script, causing issues with the script execution.  Currently, if i was to execute this script, i would get an error "unexpected token <" and it would show half the script as text ( { }); with the mobile advert displayed.

**Ad Switching Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($(window).width() > 768) {
      <?php include 'topAdvertDesktop.php'; ?>
  } else {
      <?php include 'topAdvertMobile.php'; ?>
  }
});
</script>
```

**PHP Script (Both pretty much look the same)**

```
<script src="http://tag.contextweb.com/TagPublish/getjs.aspx?action=VIEWAD&cwrun=200&cwadformat=728X90&cwpid=558488&cwwidth=728&cwheight=90&cwpnet=1&cwtagid=370138"></script>
```

I'm under the impression that i may need to enclose the javascript inside the php script but wouldn't that stop the script from executing?

Comment: php is executed by the server, javascript by the browser. This cannot work.

Comment: This isn't possible the way you're trying to do it, because PHP will be executed on the server site. Javascript will be executed on the client site, so the PHP would be executed before the JS is by the client. You need to search after `ajax` and do it with ajax calls

Comment: So it would be the same process except there would be two ajax calls (the correct one dependant on width)? Wouldn't that end up being fairly resource heavy?

Answer (score 2):

This way is not right, You should use `.load` which will make a AJAX call and will load the PHP script in any `#selector`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($(window).width() > 768) {
      $("#selector").load('topAdvertDesktop.php');
  } else {
      $("#selector").load('topAdvertMobile.php');
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Note that those PHP files must echo JSON, HTML or something else that JS can work with.

Comment: But if there's simply a javascript script in the php files (for the sake of maintenance , i'm trying to make updating the scripts a lot easier by having separate php files), are you saying i have to echo the script?

Comment: It does look like the PHP returns another JS script. `$.getScript()` maybe beneficial.